# How to integrate two .apk files

Tags: android

My problem is, I have two android apps. first one is UI app(Activity). second one is non-UI app(Service). How can you integrate both apps and install together?....

Answer (score 2):

Both of those are components, not applications. The application is the entire project put together, whereas the components are made up of different Android APK classes. See:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

You need to add both the activity and service to the manifest file.
From your UI activity, you can call startService() to start the service. Make sure to read up on life-cycles too.

Comment: I really admire your answer. But you have missed judge my question. Assume that you have two applications i mentioned in my question. When you installed that you can see two different apps in the screen(UI app, Service app). But my situation is you have to install both apps at once like one .apk

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<service>` tag inside your [Android.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)